# ReactJS doesn't throw any errors. How to fix?

Tags: reactjs

Ok. I am building my first ReactJS app. I am using React Router. Both libraries are the latest version.

The problem is, that ReactJS rarely throws any errors. It just silently decide not to render anything when something is wrong.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there some way to turn on errors in React? I'm really slowed down by the inability to debug what is going on.

Comment: Do you have an example? Are you using JSX?

Comment: are you checking the console?  If you're just looking for the expected error message to show up in the browser it won't.  Google Chrome will always display some sort of error message if you code fails and renders nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was wrapping React.render in a promise that consumed/muted all the errors.

Lesson learned :-)

Comment: Could you please share a workaround for Promises? I feel like something similar happens to my app too, with Promises making React fail without showing any errors.

Comment: I just stopped wrapping React.render in a Promise.